# Why am I getting the default value the first time running the app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm following the steps [laid out here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-adding-settings-to-app?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3) for using the Settings Activity Template and despite some changes (e.g. now a `root_preferences.xml` file gets created instead of multiple XML files for different preference screens when selecting the Settings Activity template) I pretty much have nailed down the steps very similarly.

It says towards the end:

> The first time you run the app, you should see "-1" displayed in the
> Toast because you haven't changed the setting yet.

However, instead of -1, I'm seeing US as the toast message. I'm thinking that's because it's the default value, but they also set the default value as the US, yet the expectation according to the instructions is -1 the first time they run the app...how come?

Here is my code and the result I'm getting first time running the app:

**SettingsActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.droidcafe;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent =
                    new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, mOrderMessage);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
            R.xml.root_preferences, false);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String marketPref = sharedPref
            .getString("market", "-1");
    displayToast(marketPref);

}
```

**root_preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/pref_header_account">

        <ListPreference
            app:defaultValue="US"
            app:entries="@array/pref_market_titles"
            app:entryValues="@array/pref_market_values"
            app:key="market"
            app:negativeButtonText="@null"
            app:positiveButtonText="@null"
            app:title="@string/pref_title_account" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<string name="pref_header_account">Account</string>
<!-- Sync Preferences -->
<string name="pref_title_account">Market</string>
<string-array name="pref_market_titles">
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pref_market_values">
    <item>US</item>
    <item>CA</item>
    <item>UK</item>
    <item>IN</item>
    <item>JA0</item>
    <item>-1</item>
</string-array>
```

First time running the app:

[image: US]

Expectation: -1

I realize the default value is US, but their codelab default is also US, yet the codelab says it should display first time -1.

[image: default]

Comment: Hi there Cataster. I've repaired a number of spellings in your posts - the number of them is distracting and makes questions harder to read. The sheer number of them suggests they are being made for stylistic reasons i.e. they are deliberate. That doesn't work so well for Stack Overflow, where good on-topic posts are kept for posterity.

Comment: For your reference I list here the misspellings across your account. 14 instances of ive; 14 didnt; 34 im; 13 cant; 12 whats; 34 doesnt; 22 thats; 46 dont; 10 isnt. There are two more (lets and its) but the (mis)spelling of those are dependent on context.

Comment: @halfer Oh come on, we really going as far as apostrophes now?

Comment: I am intrigued by the inference - that one kind of spelling error is less of an error than another. It's simplest if we just say that an English spelling checker can clear up any disagreements - if you get wavy underlines in your browser then please fix them. I believe that to be the community view. Thanks!

Comment: (I acknowledge that can't and won't are troublesome, because cant (bluster intended to mislead) and wont (preference or habit) are also correctly spelled words, though these are possibly regarded as arcane these days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why, but I went ahead and recreated the project and this time I checked the sub-screens settings when creating a settings activity template to create various settings screens instead of the root_preferences screen.

[image: subscreens]

This time I see -1 displayed the first time so it's working this way now.